# visual basic for applications fibonacci sequence in excel

Tags: excel, vba, fibonacci

I want to write a macro that will take an integer N from the current cell and in the cells directly below it calculates next values of Fibonacci sequence. Could you give me a clue where did i make a mistake?

```
Sub Fib()

Dim N, i, f0, f1, sum, Fib, column, row  As Integer

f0 = 0
f1 = 1
N = ActiveCellv.Value
sum = 0
column = ActiveCell.column
row = ActiveCell.row
   
   
If N = 0 Then
    Fib = f0
ElseIf N = 1 Then
    Fib = f1
Else
    For i = 2 To N
        sum = f0 + f1
        f0 = f1
        f1 = sum
    Next i
    Fib = sum
End If
    
For i = row + 1 To N + 1
    Cells(i, column).Value = Fib
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the output as written?

Comment: @nicomp for N = 6, it gives me '8' in next 6 cells below

Comment: Put a print statement in the for loop and monitor sum, f1, and f0

Answer (score 2):

firstly, `Dim N, i, f0, f1, sum, Fib, column, row  As Integer` is only declaring the last variable `row` as an integer - my suggestion would be declare all explicuitly *and* put option explicit at top.

Because `N` is currently being declared as an object, when you test `N=0` it fails because N is value `empty`

secondly `For i = row + 1 To N + 1` i think does not make sense - the output is a single value I think

I think this solves it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Fib()



Dim N As Integer, sum As Integer, Fib As Integer, column As Integer, row  As Integer

Dim f0 As Integer
Dim f1 As Integer

f0 = 0
f1 = 1
N = ActiveCell.Value
sum = 0
   
   
If N = 0 Then
     Fib = f0
ElseIf N = 1 Then
    Fib = f1
Else
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To N
        sum = f0 + f1
        f0 = f1
        f1 = sum
    Next i
    Fib = sum
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Fib

End Sub
```

You may also want to write as a user defined function:

```
Option Explicit
Function Fib(ByVal N As Long) As Long

  Dim f0 As Long
  Dim f1 As Long
  
  f0 = 0
  f1 = 1
  Fib = 0
     
     
  If N = 0 Then
       Fib = f0
  ElseIf N = 1 Then
      Fib = f1
  Else
      Dim i As Long
      For i = 2 To N
          Fib = f0 + f1
          f0 = f1
          f1 = Fib
      Next i
  End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

u can use array for n wanted fibo string as sub or easly change it to function

```
Sub test()
Dim fibNo As Integer
fibNo = ActiveCell.Value
If fibNo < 3 Then MsgBox "error": Exit Sub

Dim fibArray() As Integer

ReDim fibArray(fibNo)

fibArray(1) = 1
fibArray(2) = 1

For i = 3 To fibNo
    fibArray(i) = fibArray(i - 2) + fibArray(i - 1)
Next i
For i = 1 To fibNo
    ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = fibArray(i)
Next i

End Sub
```